# Latest Magento 2.3.3 version Product Attribute Length, Width, Height

Tags: magento2, magento-shipping

Recently Magento has released it new Version 2.3.3 which has a lot of updates.

One which is more affecting the Product Page is Product Dimensions i.e Length, Width and Height.

Till version 2.3.2 by default we have these 3 attributes on Product Detail page as below
[image]

But in new Version there are no such attributes there

[image]

I need to know if someone can tell me how to get these back there on Product page.

These fields are from Temando Shipping Module (Magento Default).

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.3.3 I see dimensions of product below:
[image]

Comment: Yeah I can see these when I delete source model for "ts" attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This is an acknowledged bug with Magento 2.3.3, see the following issue for more information.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24948

If you are not using Magento Shipping but have been using the product attributes installed by the Temando_Shipping module disabling the module will let you access the attributes again.

```
bin/magento module:disable Temando_Shipping
```

You may also need to manually edit the eav_attribute database table and make the source model null for all ts attributes.

Comment: Yes you are right but I just wanted if someone has some hot fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

For a hot fix one just need to update the `source_model` as `NULL` of the `ts_packaging_type` attribute code to see the dimensions attributes in **Mag 2.3.3** .
It can be done directly from the **Database** or as I have made a script for this purpose.